# How to make a dynamic order in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a dictionary declared like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Part, object>>> _orders = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Part, object>>>()
    {
        {"Name", x => x.Name}, //string
        {"Code", x => x.Code}, //string
        {"EnterPrice", x => x.EnterPrice}, //decimal
        {"ExitPrice", x => x.ExitPrice}, //decimal
        {"IsActive", x => (bool)x.Active }, //bool
        {"Quantity", x => x.Quantity}, //decimal
        {"Reserved", x => x.Reserved}, //decimal
    };
```

I try to bring data using the following code:

```
    NameValueCollection filter = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.RequestUri.Query);
    string sortField = filter["sortField"];
    string sortOrder = filter["sortOrder"];
    Func<IQueryable<Part>, IOrderedQueryable<Part>> orderBy = x => x.OrderBy(p => p.Id);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortField) && _orders.ContainsKey(sortField))
    {
        bool sortMode = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) && sortOrder != "desc";
        if (sortMode)
        {
            orderBy = x => x.OrderBy(_orders[sortField]);
        }
        else
        {
            orderBy = x => x.OrderByDescending(_orders[sortField]);
        }
    }
    return Ok(this.DbService.Query(null, filterQuery));
```

And `Query` method is:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> Query(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, bool noTracking = true)
{

    IQueryable<TEntity> query = DbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }
    if (orderBy != null) query = orderBy(query);
    return noTracking ? query.AsNoTracking() : query;
}
```

But when the sort column is not `string` I obtain the following exception

`"Unable to cast the type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.","ExceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()"}`

I think that the dictionary declaration and/or initialization is wrong because if I do not have any sort set by browser then the default order will be `x=>x.Id` (which is declared inline) and it doesn't crash even if `Id` is `long`. Can I declare the dictionary in a different way to solve my problem?

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I removed the dictionary and I added the following extension which receive the field name and sort mode as parametters

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering, bool ascending = true)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        PropertyInfo property;
        Expression propertyAccess;
        if (ordering.Contains('.'))
        {
            // support to be sorted on child fields.
            String[] childProperties = ordering.Split('.');
            property = type.GetProperty(childProperties[0]);
            propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
            for (int i = 1; i < childProperties.Length; i++)
            {
                property = property.PropertyType.GetProperty(childProperties[i]);
                propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(propertyAccess, property);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            property = typeof(T).GetProperty(ordering);
            propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        }
        var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
                                                         ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending",
                                                         new[] { type, property.PropertyType }, source.Expression,
                                                         Expression.Quote(orderByExp));
        //return  source.OrderBy(x => orderByExp);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(resultExp);
    }
}
```

Also solution provided by **Ivan Stoev** works

Comment: put your solution under the answer's section.don't mix it with the question.

Comment: Sorry! I wanted to put it there, but in the past somebody told me that when I found a solution for my own problem I should edit question.

Comment: If you don't post your answer as an answer, then others cannot vote on it. Also, provided you felt it was the best answer, you wouldn't be able to accept it as the best answer. Lose/lose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dictionary definition is ok - there is no good way to declare it to have values with different type.

The problem is that `Expression<Func<T, object>>` definition generates additional [`Expression.Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx) for value type properties. To make it work with EF, the convert expression must be removed and corresponding `Queryable` method must be called dynamically. It can be encapsulated in a custom extension method like this:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector, bool ascending)
    {
        var selectorBody = keySelector.Body;
        // Strip the Convert expression
        if (selectorBody.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            selectorBody = ((UnaryExpression)selectorBody).Operand;
        // Create dynamic lambda expression
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(selectorBody, keySelector.Parameters);
        // Generate the corresponding Queryable method call
        var queryBody = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
            ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending",
            new Type[] { typeof(T), selectorBody.Type },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(queryBody); 
    }
}
```

and the usage in your scenario could be like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortField) && _orders.ContainsKey(sortField))
    orderBy = x => x.OrderBy(_orders[sortField], sortOrder != "desc");
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I did a cast at return statement and it works. However I found another solution for `Orderby` extension I will edit my answer in case somebody needs it.

Comment: The solution you found is another way to achieve the goal. The only drawback compared to the dictionary approach is that it's unsafe due to hard coding the property names.

Comment: Yes you have right. I will keep boot solution for the feature.