# Create lambda expression for OrderBy based on string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

The method `MyMethod` as a string parameter. Based on the value of this parameter, I'd like get back an expression to use with an `OrderBy`. I don't find the right syntax for `Expression<Func<>>` to use with the dictionary (as `TValue` type)

```
public void MyMethod(string orderBy)
{
    var dico = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "property1", x => x.Name},
        { "property2", x => x.Age},
    };

    dico.TryGetValue("property1", out string myOrder);

    myList.OrderBy(myOrder)......

}
```

Update :

```
var dico = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Person, xxxxx>>>
{
    { "property1", x => x.Name},
    { "property2", x => x.Age},
};
```

Thanks,

Comment: How do you get `x.Name`? What is the type of `x` (inside the dictionary)?

Comment: If `x` is `Student`, you can declare the dictionary by this at best: `new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Student,object>>`

Comment: @mshsayem see my update but what to replace xxxxx  ?

Comment: As there could be properties of different types, it should be`object`

Comment: Now if this is an expression operating on `Person`, you can not use it to `OrderBy` some `Product`s, as in `_context.Prodcuts.OrderBy(...)`.

Comment: @Kris-I It really depends on query provider. if `_context.Products` is EF6 `IQueryable`, the `object` will not work for value types (for instance if `Age` is `int`). That's why the only common type is `LambdaExpression`, but then you need  a special way to apply it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685787/how-to-make-a-dynamic-order-in-entity-framework).

Comment: @Nkosi it's nothing about EF (I remove the _context in my sample). The UI send  as parameter (the column  name to order) to the service. With this value I get the expression to order the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may get hints from this:

```
public void MyMethod(string orderBy)
{
    // Assuming Product has 'Name' and 'Age' property ?
    var dico = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Product,object>>>
    {
        { "property1", x => x.Name},
        { "property2", x => x.Age},
    };

    Expression<Func<Product,object>> myorder;
    dico.TryGetValue(orderBy, out myOrder);

    _context.Products.OrderBy(myOrder);
}
```

Comment: 'may get hints' implies this isn't really an answer. Particularly since at least one query provider (EF6 for example) won't let you do this on value typed columbse

Comment: It's not about EF it's just a linq question. I changed the "_context" by a list.